# How I can Get Best Seller Products also all catalog products in grid Magento2.3.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, reports, magento2.3.3, best-seller

I want to Get bestseller report in Product first show all filter getting then rest of it in grid.

I want in magento2.3.x version in. Any one have idea? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Test/Demo/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="customer_register_success">
            <observer name="persistent" instance="Test\Demo\Observer\ChangeCustomerEmail" />
        </event>
    </config>


<?php

namespace Test\Demo\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCustomerEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    const CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID = 2;

    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $customer->setEmail('test@test.com');
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
    }
}
```